# Prove or disprove: $\frac{a_{\lceil a_n\rceil}}{a_n} \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove (or disprove) the following statement:

> Let $a_n$ be a non-decreasing sequence s.t. $\frac{a_n}{n} \rightarrow
>  \infty $.
>
> Prove or disprove:
>
> $$\frac{a_{\lceil a_n\rceil}}{a_n} \rightarrow \infty$$

Suppose $\lim\frac{a_{\lceil a_n\rceil}}{a_n} ≠\infty$.

Since $a_n$ is monotonic there exists $m >0$ s.t. $a_{\lceil a_n\rceil} < ma_n$.

Now, im not so sure how to get a contradiction to $\frac{a_n}{n} \rightarrow
 \infty $.

Any hints will be appericiated.

Comment: What does $[a_n]$ stand for?

Comment: @AlexProvost [] is the ceiling function

Comment: Please edit your question to add that `[]` is a ceiling function. I prefer to use `\lceil` and `\rceil` myself for clarity.

Comment: @babbupandey Thanks. Edited.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean "$a_n$ is not monotonic". And "there exists $m>0$ s.t. $a_{\lceil a_n \rceil} < m a_n$" for what $n$: there's one $m$ where it's true for all $n$? For each $n$ there's such an $m$?

Comment: $$\frac{a_{\lceil a_n\rceil}}{a_n}=\frac{a_{\lceil a_n\rceil}}{\lceil a_n \rceil} \frac{\lceil a_n \rceil}{a_n}\geq \frac{a_{\lceil a_n\rceil}}{\lceil a_n \rceil}.$$

Comment: @aschepler You are right, my bad. It should be $a_n$ is monotinic. What I wanted to say, Is that $a_{[a_n]}/a_n$ is bounded, so multiplying by $a_n$ gives the inequality.

Comment: You can't go from supposing $\lim b_n = \infty$ is false to saying $b_n$ is bounded. If $\lim b_n$ exists and is finite, then $b_n$ is bounded, but there's a third case that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: but since $a_{[a_n]}$ grows faster than $a_n$, and the sequence is monotonic, i guess the limit must exist, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\frac{a_{\lceil a_n\rceil}}{a_n}=\frac{a_{\lceil a_n\rceil}}{\lceil a_n \rceil} \frac{\lceil a_n \rceil}{a_n}\geq \frac{a_{\lceil a_n\rceil}}{\lceil a_n \rceil}.$$
Now show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \lceil a_n \rceil =\infty$ to conclude.

Comment: Ive already been there, It is straight forward that $\frac{a_{\lceil a_n\rceil}}{a_n} \geq \frac{a_{\lceil a_n\rceil}}{\lceil a_n \rceil}.$ The conclusion is not immediate, still trying to prove it.

Comment: Well, write $m=\lceil a_n \rceil$, then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{\lceil a_n \rceil}}{\lceil a_n\rceil}= \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_m}{m}=\infty.$$ I did not claim it is obvious. But you asked for hints not a complete solution.

Comment: I see now! thanks.

Comment: I am a bit puzzled by the downvote. If the person could care to elaborate, that would be appreciated...